# Recycler view making first item as a header

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have implemented a recycler view with sticky headers , now i implemented a searchview everything is working like a charm! but one thing is causing problem is that the first item in my filtered list is inflating header layout.And thus it becomes header , can anyone tell me what is the problem

Adapter Class

```
    class RecyclerMenuAdapter() : StickyAdapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
public var flag = false
    var headerPosition = 0
    private val LAYOUT_HEADER = 0
    private val LAYOUT_CHILD = 1
    private var  listItems : ArrayList<Menu2act.Section>? = null
    private var context : Context ? = null
    private var  orig : ArrayList<Menu2act.Section> ? = null
    constructor(listItems1: ArrayList<Menu2act.Section>?, context: Context?) : this() {

        this.listItems = listItems1
        this.context = context
      orig =ArrayList<Menu2act.Section>()
        orig!!.addAll(listItems1!!)

    }


    override fun onCreateHeaderViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return createViewHolder(parent!!,LAYOUT_HEADER)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        var  inflater : LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(p0!!.context)
        return if(p1 == LAYOUT_HEADER ) {
            var hvh = HeaderViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.seperator,p0,false))



            hvh
        } else {
            var ivh = ItemViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,p0,false))

            ivh

        }

    }

    override fun onBindHeaderViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, headerPosition: Int) {
        var helper = holder as HeaderViewHolder
        helper.textView!!.text = listItems!!.get(headerPosition).getName()

    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if(listItems!!.get(position).isHeader()) {
            LAYOUT_HEADER
        } else {
            LAYOUT_CHILD
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listItems!!.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, p1: Int) {

        if(listItems!!.get(p1).isHeader())
        {
            var helper = p0 as HeaderViewHolder
            helper.textView!!.text = listItems!!.get(p1).getName()
        }
        else
        {
            var helper = p0 as ItemViewHolder
            helper.textView!!.text = listItems!!.get(p1).getName()
            helper.textCost!!.text = listItems!!.get(p1).getItemCost()

        }

    }

    override fun getHeaderPositionForItem(itemPosition: Int): Int {
        var currentPosition = itemPosition
        do {
            if ((listItems!!.get(currentPosition).isHeader())) {
                headerPosition = currentPosition
                println("header position"+headerPosition)
                break
            }
            currentPosition -= 1
        } while (currentPosition >= 0)

        return headerPosition
    }





    fun setFilter(search : String)
    {
        flag = true
        if(flag)
        {


        }
        println("orig"+orig!!)
        var query = search.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
        listItems!!.clear()
        println("orig"+orig!!)
        if(query.isEmpty())
        {
            listItems!!.addAll(orig!!)
            flag = false

        }
        else
        {
            for(wp in orig!!)
            {
                if(wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(query) && !wp.isHeader())
                {
                    listItems!!.add(wp)
                    println("list item header"+wp.isHeader())

                }
            }

        }
             notifyDataSetChanged()


    }



    open inner class HeaderViewHolder :  RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        var textView: TextView? = null
        constructor(itemView : View) : super(itemView) {


                 textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryText)

             }




    }
    open class ItemViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        var textView: TextView? = null
        var textCost :  TextView? = null
       constructor(itemView : View) : super(itemView) {

 textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemad)
           textCost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cost

           )




       }


    }
}
```

Comment: Post the entire adapter code, please

Comment: Done please check.! @S-Sh

Comment: Solved It! anyways thx everyone

Answer (score 2):

the first step must be declared a field in the adapter like blew

```
private val HEADER_ITEM = 0
private val NORMAL_ITEM = 1
```

so, the next step you must create two type instance viewHolder

```
inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var title: TextView = itemView.item_text

}

inner class HeaderMyViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var title: TextView = itemView.item_header_text
}
```

and create a new instance suitable viewHolder

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    return if (viewType == NORMAL_ITEM) {
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
        vh = MyViewHolder(v)
        vh as MyViewHolder
    } else {
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_header, parent, false)
        vh = HeaderMyViewHolder(v)
        vh as HeaderMyViewHolder
    }
}
```

don't forget override getItemViewType

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return when (getItems()[position]) {
        is HeaderSampleModel -> HEADER_ITEM
        else -> NORMAL_ITEM
    }
}
```

last step bind item with suitable data

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    when (holder) {
        is MyViewHolder -> {
            vh = holder
            val model = getItems()[position] as SampleModel
            (vh as MyViewHolder).title.text = model.getId().toString()
        }
        else -> {
            vh = holder
            val model = getItems()[position] as HeaderSampleModel
            (vh as HeaderMyViewHolder).title.text = model.getText()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please look at the edited Code.. Everything i have done is with the same pattern you provided!

Comment: you can compare your code with this https://github.com/alirezat775/carousel-view/blob/development/app/src/main/java/alirezat775/carouselview/SampleAdapter.kt